# frequent itemsets using apriori algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apriori

I have a dataset which looks like this.[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl7b1.jpg). The image shows only a small part of data. I want to write a function which takes the dataset and k(the no. of items the frequent itemset will contain) as input and gives the k-frequent itemset along with their support as output. I have tried this.    `from itertools import combinations,product
col_list = list(df.columns) # df is my dataframe
min_support = 8.43 # minimum support given
def freq_set(df, n):
    if n == 1:
        return(a) # a is the output of 1-frequent itemset
    l = []
    support = {}
    col_comb = list(combinations(col_list,n))
    for i in col_comb:
        s = df.groupby(list(i)).size()
        L = s.index[s > min_support].tolist()
        k = 0
        for m in L:
            temp = list(combinations(m,n-1))
            for j in temp:
                if j in freq_set(df,n-1)[0]:
                    l.append(m)
                    support[m] = s.loc[L].values[k]
                break
            k += 1
    return(l,support)`    where a is`def freq_set1(df):
    l = []
    s = {}
    for i in df.columns:
        for j in df[i].unique():
            temp = 0
            for k in df[i]:
                if j==k:
                    temp += 1
            if temp > min_support:
                l.append(j)

                s[j] = temp
    return(l,s)
a = freq_set1(df)`
but it's not working.

Comment: Hi, have you checked the *Apyori* package? It might be able to help you. Also please post the data as a code chunk please.

Comment: @FedericoGarza I got a package called apriori but it's not doing what i want.

Comment: Take a look at [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apyori/1.0.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apyori/1.0.0)